# Strange super () return behaviour when using a temp variable to store the super return value

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

Pythionans

Why would these 2 functions return a different value when using a temp return result?

I have never seen this behaviour before and need to understand why.
Any clues or ideas?

```
def _store_get_values(self, cr, uid, ids, fields, context=None):
    return super(pai, self)._store_get_values(cr, uid,  ids, fields, context)
```

Returns

```
[(10, 'pai', [13484L], ['line_next_approver_id', 'next_approver_id', 'line_id', 'partner_id'])]
```

And

```
def _store_get_values(self, cr, uid, ids, fields, context=None):
    result = super(pai, self)._store_get_values(cr, uid, ids, fields, context)
    return result
```

Returns

```
[(10, 'pai', [13485L], ['line_id', 'next_approver_id', 'partner_id', 'line_next_approver_id'])]
```

I have this in the openerp/odoo framework. But I believe this has nothing to do with the framework logic but with Python ways

Comment: I don't believe Python itself plays some role here. That would be *really* strange. I think that `_store_get_values` does not give any guarantee in the order of the returned values (much like `set()` or `dict()`). FWIW, also the number is different: 13484 vs 13485.

Comment: The number is a sequence of the db. But why is the behaviour consequent in calling both ways. Always the same result in call it style A or style B

Comment: The fact that it is consistent is probably itself an arbitrary decision that you should not rely on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [sourcecodebrowser.com](http://sourcecodebrowser.com/openerp-server/5.0.0-3/classbin_1_1osv_1_1orm_1_1orm.html):

```
02486     def _store_get_values(self, cr, uid, ids, fields, context):
02487         result = {}
02488         fncts = self.pool._store_function.get(self._name, [])
02489         for fnct in range(len(fncts)):
02490             result.setdefault(fncts[fnct][0], {})
02491             ids2 = fncts[fnct][2](self,cr, uid, ids, context)
02492             for id in filter(None, ids2):
02493                 result[fncts[fnct][0]].setdefault(id, [])
02494                 result[fncts[fnct][0]][id].append(fnct)
02495         result2 = []
02496         for object in result:
02497             k2 = {}
02498             for id,fnct in result[object].items():
02499                 k2.setdefault(tuple(fnct), [])
02500                 k2[tuple(fnct)].append(id)
02501             for fnct,id in k2.items():
02502                 result2.append((fncts[fnct[0]][4],object,id,map(lambda x: fncts[x][1], fnct)))
02503         result2.sort()
02504         return result2
```

This code seems the result of a [code golf challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), however... `result2.append(...)` is the line that is producing your result. Let's take a closer look at it:

```
result2.append((
    fncts[fnct[0]][4],
    object,
    id,
    map(lambda x: fncts[x][1], fnct)
))
```

The result of `map()` is the list that is giving you problems. The order of items returned by `map()` depends on the order of items in `fnct`.

What is `fnct`? It comes from `k2`. `k2` was generated from `result[object]`. `result` is generated from `ids2`. `ids2` is the result of a call to `fncts[fnct][2]`. `fncts` is taken from `self.pool._store_function`.

So, look at the source of your `_store_function` and you'll find the answer.